# Batch convert HTML to PDF with custom paper size

Tags: pdf, html, adobe-acrobat

I have around 200 HTML files that I need to convert to PDFs. The tricky bit is that I need to convert it to a custom paper size (in this case, 5.4" x 7.2"). Acrobat 9 won't let me batch convert to a custom size. Is there any way I can do this without going in and manually printing each individual file to PDF?

I primarily use Windows 7, but I'm not averse to a (Debian) Linux solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux, [HTMLDOC](http://www.htmldoc.org/) or [html2ps](http://user.it.uu.se/~jan/html2ps.html) will do the work for you. HTMLDOC might give prettier results and can output directly to PDF. Should go like `for htmlfile in *html; do htmldoc $htmlfile; done`

Comment: Another `htmldoc` user here. A couple things: it has the `--size pagesize` option, you probably want `--size 5.4x7.2in`. To avoid dedicated title pages and TOCs, use `--webpage`. `--fontsize size` lets you pick a size. `--bodyfont serif` will use the serif font — this is needed because, somehow, the default font `htmldoc` uses causes issues when rendering links (the underline is simply placed in the wrong place). Also, note that htmldoc expects iso8859-1, so if the documents have incompatible encodings (i.e. something other than iso8859-1 or ASCII), use, e.g., `iconv`.

Comment: Also, with `htmldoc`, the emphasis is on generating a printed, for reading, copy of the document (I usually even set wider margins and remove some stuff from the code (like tables)), so the result is *not* focused on faithfulness. As `wkhtmltopdf` actually uses a rendering engine, that should be something to look at if your goal is a "1:1" copy of what's on the screen.

Comment: Thanks! my commmand line looked something like the following: `for html in *.html; do htmldoc --size 5.4x7.2in --top 0.1in --bottom 0.15in --left 0.15in --right 0.15in --bodyfont serif --footer ... --webpage -f "$html".pdf "$html"; done`

Answer (score 2):

I use [WKHTMLTOPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), which lets you set the paper size and makes very accurate PDFs.

You can use a bash script to do many in one go, as Noam explained.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I may have finally found a way to generate something better than the Firefox printing feature! It allows me to do the same that `htmldoc` does, perhaps with a way better rendering. Also, `--enable-javascript`, sounds like something useful when printing weirder sites.

Answer (score 0):

Windows utility for batch converting HTML files to PDF documents...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/html-to-pdf/

The 'Paper Size' control on the user interface accepts numeric input, allowing you to specify a custom paper size in postscript points. So, for 5.4 x 7.2 inches you'll need to enter "0 0 389 518" for portrait.

The utility also enables you to control JavaScript, font embedding, 'live links' and other stuff.